# How to get a <table> like row/column alignment in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I have a table of three columns that I want to flex column wrap to display as many rows as possible without scrolling. I started out with `<table><tr><td>` elements, but when I made the table `display: flex`, it lost it's table functionality and now the columns are not aligned. I managed to at least right-align the right-most column with `float` but I actually want it left aligned:

[image]

My simplified code as it is at the moment (the `{}` are Svelte commands providing the data and looping):

```
       <table class="flexContainer">
       {#each listingDetail as col,idx}
         <tr class="column">
           <td class="colName">
             <span class="colId">{getValue(col,"INTERNAL_COLUMN_ID")}</span>
             <span class="colName">{getValue(col,"COLUMN_NAME")}</span>
           </td>
           <td class="colTypeDDL">
             <span class="colTypeDDL">{getValue(col,"DATATYPE_PSEUDO_DDL")}</span>
           </td>
         </tr>
       {/each}
       </table>

    
    <style>
     .flexContainer {
       overflow-x: auto;
       height: calc(100% - 17em);
       display: flex;
       flex-flow: column wrap;
     }

     td.colName {
       float: left;
     }

     td.colTypeDDL {
       float: right;
     }

     span.colName {
       position: relative;
       font-weight: bold;
       margin-right: 0.5em;
     }

     span.colTypeDDL {
       position: relative;
       font-family: 'Consolas', monospace;
     }

     span.colId {
       display: inline-block;
       width: 2.5em;
       text-align: right;
       margin-right: 1em;
       font-weight: 900;
     }
    </style>
```

How can I get the datatypes (VARCHAR2, NUMBER, etc..) to be left aligned with each other like a normal table column would do, yet still have this flexbox wrap functionality? I do not want to set a fixed column width for the either column. They are usually < 30 chars but could be as long as 128 so I want it to only use the space actually needed.

Comment: Is the image what your code currently does or what you want it to do?

Comment: "I made the table display: flex"... Tip: whenever you change the display type of `table` or any table-internal element (`td`, `tr`, `thead`, etc), you're entering a world of pain. The browser starts putting anonymous wrapper boxes around stuff that you will never know about or know how to control. Either put your flexboxes around your tables (i.e. make tables be flex items) or put a flexbox as a `div` inside your table cells. Don't intermingle them.

Comment: The image is what it currently does. I'm trying to change the right column to be left-aligned under itself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Svelte so I can't help you with getting the data. But for the layout you can try this. It's responsive and I added borders/padding/margins so you can see how it works.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 10px
}

.table-row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.number{
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue
}

.entry {
  flex:1;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="table-row">
        <p class="number">1.</p>
        <p class="entry">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <p class="number">2.</p>
        <p class="entry">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <p class="number">3.</p>
        <p class="entry">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="table-row">
        <p class="number">56.</p>
        <p class="entry">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <p class="number">57.</p>
        <p class="entry">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <p class="number">58.</p>
        <p class="entry">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="table-row">
        <p class="number">205.</p>
        <p class="entry">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <p class="number">206.</p>
        <p class="entry">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="table-row">
        <p class="number">207.</p>
        <p class="entry">Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't this require me to know how many items per column and also fix the # of columns?

Comment: The number of columns is fixed (3, but you can change that if you want) but you would need to know the amount of entries and write the html for it. It can be tedious for a big number of entries. Depending on how retrieving the data works, you can try a forEach in js and create a .table-row element (+children + insert data where needed) for each entry and then append it to the grid. Then you can use a :nth-child(3n+1) -will vary- to reorder elements in the grid by adding an extra class to that element that gets it starting from the second/third column, such as grid-column-start: 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: @PaulW, you want precisely 3 columns, right?

Comment: No, i have an unlimited, unexpected number of items that should flow into however many columns needed to fill out the available space as they resize their browser. I know I can do this in Javascript and Svelte but hoping for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this with only CSS.  If you're willing to define a hard-coded min/max width for your 3 big columns, and also a hard-coded width for your smaller VARCHAR column, then you can get pretty close, but it will mean that occasionally, if you have an unusually long string in the table, that it will either wrap or get truncated.  If that's ok, then you can do something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmtnc516/1/)